# Fastest C++ way to convert float to string

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, formatting

I have encountered problem of converting float to string where `to_string` is too slow for me as my data might involves few millions floats.

I already have solution on [how to write those data out fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741702/write-data-from-c-vector-to-text-file-fast/29743260#29743260).

However, after solving that problem, I soon realized that the conversion of float to string is leaving a big impact.

So, is there any ideas or solution for this other than using other non standard library?

Comment: How many numbers, what format do you want, and how long does your current implementation take on which processor?

Comment: @gnasher729, Hi, actually i have about 2 millions of vertices with its coordinates of xyz in floats. As i wish to output those information to obj file, i need to convert it into string(eg: "V" + pos.x+ " "...). current implementation of to_string takes about 3 minutes on low res model with roughly 300000s vertices. FYI, i am running on old 1st gen i5

Comment: which compiler are you using? you might have some performance improvements with gcc5 which uses small string optimization instead of copy on write. Clang uses SSO as well if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @dau_sama, i am using MSVC compiler from visual studio 2013 community, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimization that comes in mind is to not directly use to_string, which creates a new string every time you call it.
You probably end up copying that string too, which is not so efficient.

What you could do is to allocate a char buffer big enough to store all the string representations that you need, then use printf

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

reusing the same buffer all the time. 
If you limit the precision of your floats to a fixed amount of decimals, you can compute the offset to which your float is represented in the array.

for example if we only had an array of values:

```
index = 1;
float f = value[index];
//corrresponding 6 chars float
const char* s = char_array[index*1];
//the representation will start at position 6, and it will be null terminated so you can use it as a string
```

for clarification your char_array will look like:

```
1.2000\02.4324\0...
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my poor understanding. From what i have understood, char_array[index*1] is allocation of a big buffer, the values from all the floats will have to come into this buffer, am i correct??

Comment: Hi, dau_sama, another thing is that, how do we really know what size of buffer to be allocated??

Comment: Yes indeed, you store everything in the same buffer. If you know how many values you have, you know the size of the buffer to be allocated. If you don't know it beforehand, it can be a bit of a problem, and you'd need to grow it when you reach the limit. It just gets a bit more complicated

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification, i have managed to do it using sprintf using the buffer of char*, However, the size of the buffer to be allocated is still unknown to me. So, if the limit of buffer is reached, so how can we resize the buffer. Thanks

Comment: you know the position in the buffer you're in, you know if  the next value is going to overflow the buffer. What you need to do is to allocate (malloc) a bigger buffer and copy the old values to the new one. Once that's done, you can free the previous one :-) check also realloc.

Answer (score 19):

Here are some of the fastest algorithms for converting floating point numbers into decimal string representation:

- Grisu by Florian Loitsch: [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately with Integers](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf)
- Ryū by Ulf Adams: [Ryū: fast float-to-string conversion](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=3192369&type=pdf)
- Schubfach by Raffaello Giulietti: [The Schubfach way to render doubles](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1luHhyQF9zKlM8yJ1nebU0OgVYhfC6CBN/view)
- Dragonbox by Junekey Jeon: [Dragonbox: A New Floating-Point
  Binary-to-Decimal Conversion Algorithm](https://github.com/jk-jeon/dragonbox/blob/master/other_files/Dragonbox.pdf)

At the time of writing Dragonbox is the fastest of these methods, followed by Schubfach, then a variation of Grisu called Grisu-Exact (not to be confused with Grisu2 and Grisu3) and then Ryū:

[image]

An implementation of Dragonbox is available [here](https://github.com/jk-jeon/dragonbox). It is also included in [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) integrated into a high-level formatting API. For maximum performance you can use `format_to` with a stack-allocated buffer, for example:

```
fmt::memory_buffer buf;
fmt::format_to(buf, "{}", 4.2);
// buf.data() returns a pointer to the formatted data & buf.size() gives the size
```